# TypeScript 1.5.3 mixing external with internal modules

Tags: typescript

Does anybody know how to mix external typescript modules with internal ones. I tried it with using browserify but when i import some external module i cannot longer use internal modules(namespace or module) ?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is, [don't mix internal and external modules](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/Stop-Mixing-TypeScript-Internal-And-External-Modules/). If you are using external modules commit yourself to that pattern and act as if internal modules simply don't exist.

The TypeScript team (via Ryan Cavanaugh) [have a similar recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules).

So just ditch the internal modules / namespaces and get on board fully with the external module pattern, which is better anyhow.