# How do I use RequestPromise in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have installed [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) library and trying to use it in my TypeScript app but without much luck.

If I use it like this:

```
import {RequestPromise} from'request-promise';

RequestPromise('http://www.google.com')
        .then(function (htmlString) {
            // Process html...
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // Crawling failed...
        });
```

I see this on TS compile output:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'RequestPromise'.
```

If I use it this way:

```
import * as rp from'request-promise';

rp('http://www.google.com')
    .then(function (htmlString) {
        // Process html...
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // Crawling failed...
    });
```

I see an error that says that there is no '.then()' method on object rp.

How do I properly use it with TypeScript?

Comment: Have you tried `import rp from 'request-promise';` and then using `rp` as you have above?

Comment: Now it compiles, but I see `TypeError: Uncaught error: request_promise_1.default is not a function` now when running the app and calling that code.

Comment: I tried `import rp = require('request-promise')` and it fixed the error. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand why this works until I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706271/6137628). TL;DR - `import * as` creates a module object, which is not "callable" like a function.

Answer (score 20):

You must import all (`*`) not just `RequestPromise`:

```
import * as request from "request-promise";
request.get(...);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706164/typescript-import-as-vs-import-require) elaborates on the differences between `import/from` and `require`.

Answer (score 12):

request-promise has a package for typescript

```
npm i --save-dev @types/request-promise
import { get, put, post } from 'request-promise';
```

## Usage

```
get(options).then(body => {

    console.log(body)

}).catch(e => reject);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use request-promise in this way

```
import * as requestPromise from 'request-promise';

const options = {
    uri: _url,
    proxy: https://example.host.com:0000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
};

requestPromise.get(options, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        // Do error handling stuff
    } else {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
             // Do error handling stuff
        } else {
             // Do success stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use it as a promise (with `.then(...)`) but as a callback?