# How to use ES6 import with 'request' npm module

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules, npm-request

In ES6-ifying some TypeScript code (the project I'm working runs in both the browser and a Node server, I'd like to tree-shake the browser bundle), I'm trying to eliminate uses of `require` and only use `import`. But when I do this...

`import * as request from 'request';`

and subsequently call `request()`, I get runtime errors in Node (after using babel to make the code ES5, and thus Node, compatible):

`TypeError: request is not a function`

On the other hand, if I do this:

`import request from 'request';`

then the TypeScript compiler complains with

`error TS1192: Module '"<mypath>/node_modules/@types/request/index"' has no default export.`

If I manually change the compiled JS code to use `import request from 'request';`, it actually works fine... how can I force the TS compiler to accept this code and just pass it through?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706164

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try Add `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`: `true` to your

```
tsconfig.json
```

seems like still an open issue in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need remove comment in `tsconfig.json` at line 46, because default ts config file have this option but it's commented by default