# How to import modules in js files as you do in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

So basically the problem is this. I need to use some FCM cordova plugins in my ionic v3 project, this project as been modify so it is based in javascript.

I need to be able to import modules as I usually do in typescript files, I mean do something like this:

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';
```

But in js, so I can use methods and functions of these plugins and components in js

Currently, I'm trying by using require.js since guys bellow gave me the idea:

```
var FCM = '@ionic-native/fcm';
require([FCM], function(fcmodule){
    // use module
})
```

but it is not working so far, I'm getting these errors

[image]

Comment: this should also work in `JavaScript` but not in every browser. You could use `require()` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript import/as vs import/require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706164/typescript-import-as-vs-import-require)

Comment: But how do you bundle your modules in Typescript? I don't think it matters if you use Typescript or Javascript - it's the bundler that decides if you have to use `import` or `require`.

Answer (score 0):

There are various AMD libraries, some of them are systemjs, requireJS.

If you are using **requireJS**, you can use `var FCM=require('@ionmic-native/fcm');`.

If you are using es6+ then you will get support of `import` keyword.

Comment: so using this lib I should be able to import and use the fcm's method withouth problem right?