# Difference between `import x = require('x')` and `const x = require('x')` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

It seems `import x = require('x')` is an invalid syntax in [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015), and there isn't any clear explanation in TypeScript documentation.

Comment: `import` imports, `const` defines a constant variable....

Comment: How about difference between `import x from 'x'` and `import x = require('x')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript import/as vs import/require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706164/typescript-import-as-vs-import-require)

Comment: https://insights.untapt.com/webpack-import-require-and-you-3fd7f5ea93c0

Answer (score 36):

## Q1: `import … = require(…)` versus `const … = require(…)`

At runtime (or once the code is compiled), there is no difference between the two syntaxes, the first one is converted to the second one.

#### With `import`:

```
import x = require('x')
```

This syntax is specific to TypeScript. The constant `x` is of type given by some typing defined in the imported package or in a package `@types/x`.

#### With `const`:

```
const x = require('x')
```

This is a valid syntax in JavaScript and of course in TypeScript. In TypeScript, the constant `x` is of type `any`.

## Q2: `import … from …` versus `import … = require(…)`

> How about difference between `import x from 'x'` and `import x = require('x')`

The syntax `import … from …` is from the ES6 standard. I suggest to read [this introduction](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/) to ES6 modules and how to import and export them.

But, in short, the syntax `import x from 'x'` is equivalent to:

```
import x = require('x').default
```

*(Notice the `.default` member.)*

#### How to convert `import … = require(…)` to the ES6 syntax

The ES6 standard states that all exported members can be imported into a single *"namespace object module"*.

Then the closest standard syntax of `import x = require('x')` is:

```
import * as x from 'x'
```

This syntax currently works well with the TypeScript transpilation because the code is converted to a `const … = require(…)`.

**However:** This syntax should be used *only* in the context defined by the standard. Because, when your code will use a native version of ES6 modules, **you won't be able to import a function or a class that way**.

Answer (score 4):

The `require()` function doesn't exist in TypeScript. ECMAScript's module system uses `import` and `export` keywords. The `require`, `module.exports`, and `exports` keywords exist in the CommonJS module system used by Node.js.

So when you type `const x = require('x')`, TypeScript is going to complain that it doesn't know what `require` is. You need to install `@types/node` package to install type definitions for the CommonJS module system in order to work with it from the TypeScript.

```
├── src/
|   ├── a.ts
|   └── x.js
└── dist/
    ├── a.js
    └── x.js
```

Let's imagine you have `a.ts` and `x.js` as source files. The `a.ts` file imports `x.js` file. Both these files will be compiled to `.js` files that will run on Node. So let's understand how these will look like when compiled to JavaScript.

```js
// dist/x.js
exports = module.exports = function() { return 'MAIN'; }
exports.custom = function() { return 'CUSTOM'; }

// dist/a.js
const x = require( 'x.js' );
console.log( x() ); // 'MAIN'
console.log( x.custom() ); // 'CUSTOM'
```

The `x.js` sets `exports` and `module.exports` to a function that returns `MAIN` when called. Since a function is also an `object` in JavaScript, we can assign some properties to it. The `custom` property is a function that returns `CUSTOM` when called.

```js
// src/x.js
exports = module.exports = function() { return 'MAIN'; }
exports.custom = function() { return 'CUSTOM'; }
```

The `src/x.js` is already a `.js` file with the CommonJS module syntax. We can import it inside a TypeScript file by using `import` syntax. We need to set the `allowJs` property of `tsconfig.json` to `true` or use `--allowJs` flag while compiling the project.

#### Approach One

```
// src/a.ts
import x from './x';
console.log( x() ); // === error ===
console.log( x.custom() ); // === error ===
```

In this example, `import x` syntax states that `x` is the **default export**, however, `x.js` does not have a default export since that feature lacks in the CommonJS module system. You can allow this by setting the `esModuleInterop` option to `true` in the `tsconfig.json`. So when you try to compile this program, you are going to get the following compilation error.

```
a.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"./x"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

1 import x from './src/q';
         ~

  src/q.js:1:11
    1 exports = module.exports = function() { return "MAIN"; }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
```

#### Approach Two

```
// src/a.ts
import * as x from './x';
console.log( x() ); // `MAIN`
console.log( x.custom() ); // `CUSTOM`
```

In this example, `import * as x` syntax states that all export members will be stored in the `x` **object**. Hence, `x` itself doesn't represent anything, it is just a container that holds all the exports such as `x.custom`. However, TypeScript can inter `module.exports` as `x` and therefore this program works just fine. But according to ECMAScript specifications, `x` should not be callable or constructible (*using `new`*). So this isn't semantically right.

#### Approach Three

TypeScript provides `import = require()` and `export =` syntax to work with such situations. This syntax is limited to TypeScript only and it can be only used when the `module` property is set to `CommonJS` in the `tsconfig.json`.

The `export =` syntax represents a single object that will be exported from the module. By default, a JavaScript module with an export in the form of `module.exports` automatically obtain `export =` type.

> But you can use `exports = function(){ ... }` syntax in a TypeScript or JavaScript file. The TypeScript compiler will convert this syntax into `module.exports` syntax in the compiled JavaScript code.

```
// src/a.ts
import x = require( './x' );
console.log( x() ); // `MAIN`
console.log( x.custom() ); // `CUSTOM`
```

When a module has `exports =`  type, the ideal way to import it using `import = require()` syntax.

---

I would personally prefer to use `import x from` syntax since we can closely relate it with a CommonJS module and also, we compile the code to `ECMAScript` and `CommonJS` module system using the same syntax. By setting `esModuleInterop` option to `true` in the `tsconfig.json` file, the TypeScript compiler emits appropriate helper functions in the compiled JavaScript code to add the **default export** feature to a CommonJS module.