# Typescript auto-complete not working in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, puppeteer, intellisense

I'm trying to make use of Puppeteer within a ts file which works fine except the VSCode Intellisense stops working a soon as I'm inside a .ts and not a .js file.
I've seen some posts about this incident but none could help me. What I did:

- created a project via npm init
- installed dependencies as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
"@types/node": "^14.0.14",
"events": "^3.1.0",
"puppeteer": "^4.0.1",
"typescript": "^3.9.5" }

  "devDependencies": {
"puppeteer-tsd": "0.0.2"  }
```

- created tsconfig.json

  ```
   "target": "es5",
   "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
   "outDir": "./dist",
    .
    .
    .
   "include": ["src", "node_modules/puppeteer-tsd/src/index.d.ts"]
  ```
- created src and dist folder
- put a main.ts inside my src
- told VSCode to use the project TS version instead of its own

Then I compiled. Everything works fine. But I get no IntelliSense to help me out while I type.
So I created a .js file in my src directory, copied the code from my main.ts inside it and then I got Intellisense to work perfectly fine with all suggestions and so on. And I have no idea left what I could try except accepting it and code without it.
I'd be greatful for any suggestions on what could be the issue. Thx in advance!

**Edit**: Meanwhile I found out, that it works fine with non imported functions like console.log(). It's only Puppeteer (or probably any imported module).

**Edit 2:** [Heres a Link to my Log File.](https://pastebin.com/8JX3rGqF)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code Intellisense Typescript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394831/visual-studio-code-intellisense-typescript-not-working)

Comment: If you go to the Output panel and select TypeScript in the dropdown, what does it show?

Comment: @ ABGR Saw that one already, but thanks.

Comment: @H.B. Here you go: [Info  - 14:25:00.908] Using tsserver from: *myparentfolderpath*\node_modules\typescript\lib
[Info  - 14:25:00.912] <syntax> Forking...
[Info  - 14:25:00.926] <syntax> Starting...
[Info  - 14:25:00.928] <semantic> Forking...
[Info  - 14:25:00.939] <semantic> Starting...

Comment: Just close your project(means VSCode) and open it again and check..

Comment: @ Rohit Tagadiya Unfortunately the old "Have you turned it off and on again..?" didn't do the job this time :(

Answer (score 2):

Apart from VSCode's TypeScript language features provided by the extension `vscode.typescript-language-features` that needs to be functional, your imports must be correct for built-in or packaged (`@types/x`) type declarations of modules to be considered.

#### `import/require`:

```js
import x = require('x');
```

Gives you type awareness but is valid only in TypeScript.

#### `const/require`:

```js
const x = require('x');
```

Also valid In TypeScript but does not give you type awareness; `x` will be of type `any`.

---

For more information on module imports, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535938/9378384).