# Difference between types of import

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between

```
import * as express from 'express'
```

and

```
import express from 'express'
```

and why I am  being "obliged" to use the first one by `tsloader`?

If I use the second version, I got `undefined`

Comment: This has been asked before over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706271/2919534

Comment: I'm sure it's been asked before but that question isn't exactly the same.  If the module does not declare a `default` export, then `import express from 'express'` is a "synthetic default export" which basically packages all of the exported vars into properties of an `express` object, the same as `import * as express from 'express'` does.  You can only use `import express from 'express'` if your `.tsconfig` has `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I just checked and I have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports true`. Thanks for the explanation!