Uncaught TypeError express-handlebars
I'm trying to connect to express-handlebars.
This is my index.ts:


import * as express from 'express';
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './pages');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);



This is my vite.config.mjs


import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        open: '/',
    },
    root: resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    build: {
        outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
});



This is my package.json:


{
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.5",
    "sass": "^1.77.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^7.1.3",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.3",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-checker": "^0.6.4",
  }
}



And unfortunately I get an error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')
Why does the error appear?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Maybe this would be helpful to you?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35706271/3397771
