# Import DefinetelyTyped definition as ES6

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write sample project on knockout using TypeScript and gulp.
For knockout i wanted to use DefinetelyTyped, but faced this issue:

```
import * as ko from './ko/knockout';
var a = ko.KnockoutStatic;
```

When i try to compile this code, i get an error `error TS2306: File 'fakepath/app/ko/knockout.d.ts' is not a module.`
I have tried different ways to import this definition file, i even hoped once that it's globally declared, but it didn't work either.

How do i import ko to my `.ts` files, so i can do stuff with knockout?

Comment: see here for a description of error TS2306 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error

Comment: use  typings https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings  to install knockout.d.ts

Comment: actually the solution was pretty clear `import * as ko from 'knockout';` went fine.

Comment: clear and easy solution.  Thanks for sharing :-)