# How do I mix Typescript namespaces with External modules when "Don't do it" is not an option

Tags: node.js, typescript, namespaces, node-modules

### Situation

I have a Typescript app written using namespaces. I want to move some of this logic (Google OAuth) out of the client and into a node service. I have created a nearly complete project for that [here](https://github.com/Roaders/YouTubeOAuth/tree/Duplicate_Contracts).

This new project has a node component that will make authorisation requests to google using a secret key and a client component that can be re-used by other applications that will communicate with the server. I also have a testHarness app that uses this client to test it and make sure that I can use it in a namespace based application.

I have some shared interfaces that both the client and server consume.

I want my client code to be usable in projects that use externam modules and namespaces - i.e. my existing project.

### It must be possible

I have read in many places

> #### Do not use "namespaces" in external modules.
>
> #### Don't do this.
>
> #### Seriously. Stop.

Such as on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error) but I am still convinced that this must be possible. The reason that I think this is that in my project I have a dependency on RxJs. This project in my node_modules folder is used by both the client and the server.

### What I have tried

In my [project](https://github.com/Roaders/YouTubeOAuth/tree/Duplicate_Contracts) I have a `contracts.d.ts` file that I want to share between both the client and the server.

#### StackOverflow

I looked at this question:

[Typescript es6 import module "File is not a module error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error)

And made my contracts look like this:

```
// test.js - exporting es6
export module App {
  export class SomeClass {
    getName(): string {
      return 'name';
    }
  }
  export class OtherClass {
    getName(): string {
      return 'name';
    }
  }
}
```

and then tried the various import methods listed:

```
import * as app1 from "./test";
import app2 = require("./test");
import {App} from "./test";
```

I got each of these to work so that my server AND client compiled correctly but then as soon as I tried to compile my testHarness app - that uses namespaces - it failed:

```
src/testHarness/testHarness.ts(4,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'PricklyThistle'.
src/testHarness/testHarness.ts(4,38): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'PricklyThistle'.
```

#### Copying Declaration Files from node_modules

As I said, I am convinced that this is possible as dependencies that I import into node_modules are used by both my client and server projects and my client can still be used with internal namespaces.

To go down this route I edited a `d.ts` file in the Rx ts folder and added a new interface. I verified that both client and server could use this interface and that my testHarness app (with namespaces) woudl compile. All was good!

I then copied this edited file into my common folder. I had to rename the module to avoid conflicts but then I get:

```
src/node/youTubeAuthenticationServer.ts(3,23): error TS2306: File '/src/common/rx.test.d.ts' is not a module.
```

My edited declaration file looks like:

```
declare module RxTest {

    export interface TestInterface{
        propertyOne: string;
        propertyTwo: number;
    }

}
declare module "rx.test" { export = RxTest; }
```

### Workaround

For now I have just copied the interfaces that are used by both applications. This works and there are only 2 small interfaces so it's not a big deal. It is very anooying though. One of the great things about node is that is uses the same language as the browser. If you can't share code that is not good. I also have other much larger code bases that I want to do similar things with and in these situations copying code will not be a viable solution.

Any new projects I work on I will exlusively use external modules but when working with legacy code this is not always possible.

I really hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If find your question a bit confusing, there's too much description and too little examples (code/configuration) of what you have.

Try to do this:

```
declare module "rx.test" {
    export interface TestInterface{
        propertyOne: string;
        propertyTwo: number;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, please edit your question and add the directory structure that you have, the `tsconfig.json` file(s) that you have, explain how you build (tsc, gulp, etc) and so on.