# How to consume Typescript module

Tags: typescript, module

I have a tool that takes my C# DTO classes and creates TypeScript interfaces for them (the specific tool I am using is [here](https://github.com/originalmoose/Typescript.Definitions.Tools)). Here is an example of the output file `models.d.ts`:

```
declare module Models {
  export interface User {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to import this `User` interface in my other TypeScript files. I have tried numerous variations of the following:

```
import { User } from './models';
import * as models from './models';
import models = require('./models');
```

but all these give me the error that "`File '[...]/models.d.ts' is not a module`. I normally have the `export interface ...` sitting at the root of the file, rather than nested in a `module` block, so I am unfamiliar with how they work. I can manually (or write a script) take the interfaces and strip out the wrapping `module` lines, but if possible I'd like to be able to use the output of the tool as-is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *Check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/32805559/1679310*

Comment: @RadimKöhler Thanks for the reply. According to the replies there, I should do `export declare module Models {...}`, which does work, however I'd like to avoid manually editing the output of the tool that generates this file. Since that is the output of the tool I had assumed that there was some way to consume the module without added the `export` keyword. Is that not the case? It is a small project I found on GitHub, so it's possibly an oversight or there is some undocumented option I am missing.

Comment: Well, what is not exported.. cannot be imported, would be a simple answer. The link I gave you should show all the details about importing, but it really expects, that you exported something.. hope it helps a bit

Comment: @RadimKöhler Alright, was hoping there was something I was missing, but I guess it seems it is a problem with the tool's output. Thanks for your help!