# Typescript import index.ts is not a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, export

I am trying to import index.ts in a subfolder which has other imports. But I keep getting a typescript error.

full repo: https://github.com/Shavindra/webpack-react-sw

`(5,32): error TS2306: File 'C:/../src/reducers/index.ts' is not a module.`

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. I am using TS 2.4.1. I've tried restarting the computer/VSCode but nothing seems to work :-|

```
// ./src/reducers/counter.reducer.ts    
export const counterReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


// ./src/reducers/index.ts
export * from './counter.reducer';


// ./src/app.ts
import * as React from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Counter } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { counterReducer } from './reducers';


const store = createStore(counterReducer);
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter
        value={store.getState()}
        onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}
        onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}
    />,
    rootEl
);

render();
store.subscribe(render);

// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx":"react",
    "lib": [
      "webworker",
      "es6",
      "scripthost",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [ "node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts", "node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts", "typings/file-loader.d.ts"  ],
  "exclude": [
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: i do not see where you have import ....  from 'index';

Maybe possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error

Comment: @Digvijay it's in the app.ts?

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas are:

- reducers is a folder and tsc is trying to search for ./reducers/index.ts
- reducers is a file and is not readable by tsc
- recuders is a valid file but has a different export system. check UMD, systemjs, commonjs includes

You can include them via:

`import counterReducer = require('./recuders');
import * as counterReducer from './recuders';`

If you want to include a single module via `import { mod } from 'file';` Be sure that you export this function, class or whatever you want in reducers.ts

I hope this ideas helped. let me know!

Can you please post your tsconfig.json to ensure everything is correctly setup?

Comment: I've added the tsconfig

Comment: I tried to setup your files at my workspace and i found no errors within the .ts files. After i removed the `files` array from the tsconfig, and i tried to tsc the `app.ts` everything works fine.

May you need to add a rootDir at the tsconfig to ensure the tsc find all files?

Comment: https://github.com/Shavindra/webpack-react-sw here is my repo if it helps

Comment: I cloned your repo and i figured out that your react component works just fine. I think the problem could be solved when first:
change the tsconfig.json to use the ts@^2.x syntax like [tsconfig.json](https://pastebin.com/1i6E45eR).
Second: The service worker is not correctly setup. this should not be bundled with the file-loader plugin. this causes the error. may you find another solutition or ask if it itsn't working.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Solving tip for me was to change the "export system" in `tsconfig.json`, it was `system` for supporting single file compilation; moved it to `CommonJS` and solved. Apparently this is relevant when working with `index.ts` batch import technique.