# Is it possible to use Jest to test a type in a segmented module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, jestjs

I've been tasked with adding tests to a sdk written in typescript.  This sdk has public accessible module and an internal module, and the types within these modules span many files.  For example:

```
//CustomField.ts
module deadbreaker {
 export class CustomField {}
}

//Music.ts
module deadbreaker {
 export class Music{}
}
```

When the sdk is compiled, all the exported classes are placed into one javascript file and then the entire deadbreaker module is exported.

Using Jest as our testing framework, we've tried unsuccessfully to test the types nested inside the segmented deadbreaker module.

Test file:

```
import deadbreaker from "../../src/CustomField";

describe("CustomField Class", () => { ...})
```

Error Message: 'src/CustomField.ts' is not a module.  I understand why it's saying this, since CustomField is inside the deadbreaker module.

Is there a way that we can test the enclosed types with Jest?

Comment: If you have access to SDK, you may want to write tests inside of the SDK. I can suggest `conditional-type-checks` npm package for type testing :) PS. what's a "deadbreaker"? I hope it's a typo

Comment: @Max Thanks for the response.  We do have access to the SDK.  We've created a test directory alongside the src directory.  However, we have not be able to  import the deadbreaker module into our test files, since the module spans multiple files and is consolidated at compile time.  Additionally, we can't import the nested types.  PS: deadbreaker is just an example module name.

Comment: You say you had an issue with importing the same module files into the test files? Can you add an error message or example of wrong behavior that you see what you do that?(you can update your question)

Comment: Okay, I see, I don't know any other way, except exporting your module and then using it inside the test. Module file: `export module deadbreaker { export class CustomField {} }`. In test file: `import { dealbreaker } from '...'`

Comment: There's actually been a similar question asked in the past with the same suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/32805764/10048850

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Since the module spans multiple files, I don't think I can add the `export` keyword.