# How do you use typescript internal modules with AMD modules

Tags: typescript, amd, webpack

I'm not sure if I'm structuring my typescript incorrectly so may be asking the wrong question here.

I've got 2 related classes 1 interfaces in separate files in the same folder.

I've wrapped them in a module because that feels like what I should do coming from C#.

This is all angularjs so it does it's own DI which might be important but probably isn't.

File 1:

```
export module Module1{
    export interface IService{
    }
}
```

File2:

```
export module Module1{
    export class Implementation implements IInterface{
    ...
    }
}
```

File 3 is angular code that uses the angular injected instance of IInterface. If I import File2 using `require("./File2")` it works but I'd rather import the whole of `Module1`, something like below, so I don't have to require each class individually (as this is obviously a simplified case).

```
import authModule = require('Module1');

var assetStreamApp = angular.module("[])
    .run(['IInterface'], (instance: IInterface) => {
        instance.doSomething();
    });
```

Is this possible?

I don't want to have to import every file individually and then choose a different alias for each "module" to namespace the types when it feels like I should be able to do that once.

Edit: After a little more reading I think I've worked out some of the terminology. I want to use typescript internal modules in a project but also use AMD modules as split points so I can use webpack's code splitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should just use external modules and not mix internal with external modules.

This has been discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules) and [here](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/Stop-Mixing-TypeScript-Internal-And-External-Modules/).

I would recommend doing... IService.ts:

```
interface IService {
}

export = IService;
```

Implementation.ts:

```
import IInterface = require("./IInterface");

class Implementation implements IInterface{
...
}

export = Implementation;
```

And then import them appropriately into your file:

```
import IService = require("./IService");
import Implementation = require("./Implementation");

// use IService and Implementation here
```

**Combining Multiple Modules into One Module**

That being said, if you really wanted to, you could use `IService.ts` and `Implementation.ts` above and then create a file called `Module1.ts` where you import then export your modules like so:

```
export import IService = require("./IService");
export import Implementation = require("./Implementation");
```

Then in your code you can use it like such:

```
import Module1 = require("./Module1");

// use Module1.IService or Module1.Implementation here
```

---

**Combining Multiple Modules with ES6 Modules**

By the way, I wanted to point out that doing this is very convenient if you use ES6 modules...

IService.ts:

```
interface IService {
}

export default IService;
```

Implementation.ts:

```
import IInterface from "./IInterface";

export default class Implementation implements IInterface {
...
}
```

Module1.ts:

```
// re-export the modules
export {default as IService} from "./IService";
export {default as Implementation} from "./Implementation";
```

Then when you use this module you can easily access what you want out of it. Here are some example import statements:

```
// import only IService
import {IService} from "./Module1";
// import IService and Implementation
import {IService, Implementation} from "./Module1";
// or implement everything on a Module1 object
import * as Module1 from "./Module1";
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those links. What's the difference between that and `export interface IService`?

Comment: @BenCr `export interface IService` will export it as a property of the module instead of it being the module itself. So by using `export = IService`, and `import IService` then `IService` is the actual interface.

Comment: Ahh, great, that simplifies the aliasing so I don't have to `import module = require('');` and then use `module.IService` everywhere. Great, thanks