# Embedded modules across multiple files

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript1.6

Over the past year we built a medium size application and we are currently trying to place our code inside modules. Our challenge is that we what to work on a two level of modules the first one is at the app level and the module (architectural structure).

Here is a example of the structure we would like to build :

```
// entity.ts
module app {
    module core {
        export class Entity{}
    }
}

// BaseCustomer.ts
import {app} from "./Entity"; 
module app {
    module core {
        export class BaseCustomer extends Entity{}
    }
}
```

I found many example of a module that is created on multiple file, but I cannot find a way to have multiple embedded module created on multiple files.

Does typescript 1.6.2 support that form a implementation? How?

Comment: I try with the `export` keyword, but without success.

Comment: Don't do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules