# TypeScript: is there a way to get rid of 'import'?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am a TypeScript beginner and I am doing some project with TypeScript + Angular 1.

So far, I have some services defined, each with the following structure:

```
/// <reference path="../App.ts"/>


module SomeModule {

export class SomeService {
    constructor(...) {
    ...
    }
}

var app = AppModule.getModule();
app.service("SomeService", SomeService);
}
```

where my App.ts is:

```
module AppModule{
  'use strict';
   angular.module('SomeApp', [...]);

   export var getModule:() => ng.IModule = () => {
    return angular.module('SomeApp');
   };
}
```

And whenever I am trying to reference service that has a different module name, I need to include:

```
import SomeService = SomeModule.SomeService;
```

My question comes to: is there a way to omit those imports? Or store them in one file, so that I can later only reference one file instead of referencing all of the services which have different modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There a few things wrong with your code. The first one is that you should use `<references>` comments only yo reference type definition files `*.d.ts` not actual source files `*.ts`.

The second is that your are mixing internal and external modules and [you should never do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules/30357635#30357635).

So you can use internal modules using the `namespace` keyword. Try to avoid using the `module` keyword because it is the legacy version of `namespace. The following is a basic example:

```
// some_module.ts
namespace AppModule.SomeModule {

    export class SomeService {
        constructor() {
         // ...
        }
    }
}

// app.ts
namespace AppModule {
   angular.module('SomeApp', []);

   export function getModule() {
       return angular.module('SomeApp');
   }
}

var app = AppModule.getModule();
app.service("SomeService", AppModule.SomeModule.SomeService);
```

With external modules the same code would look as follows:

```
// some_module.ts
class SomeService {
    constructor() {
        // ...
    }
}
export default SomeService;

// app.ts
angular.module('SomeApp', []);

function getModule() {
    return angular.module('SomeApp');
}
export default getModule;


// main.ts
import getModule from "./app";
import SomeService from "./some_module";

var app = getModule();
app.service("SomeService", SomeService);
```