# TypeScript UnitTests on Module

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I want to run unit tests in typescript. I have a simple folder structure where directory app contains an app.ts like following

```
export module app {
  export class Config {
    testMe() {
      return "Hallo";
    }
  }
}
```

The unit tests that lies in directory test:

```
import app = require('../app/conf');
import * as chai from 'chai';

var config = new app.app.Config();
chai.expect(config.testMe()).to.equals("Hallo");
```

As TypeScripts documentation states in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-pitfalls-of-modules when TypeScript code is used as an external module it does not make sense to use the module concept at all.

As you can see app.app.Config is not a very elegant way.

I can only run my unit tests on compiled TypeScript code. So I can only use modules if I don't care about unit tests or is there a simpler way?

Comment: There is an excellent explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30357635/2300664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `app.ts`:

```
export class Config {
    testMe() {
        return "Hallo";
    }
}
```

and `test.ts`:

```
import app = require('../app/conf');
import * as chai from 'chai';

var config = new app.Config();
chai.expect(config.testMe()).to.equals("Hallo");
```

And if your original code worked, so will this. No more `app.app` and no more *needless internal modules*.

Comment: Thanks, I know that it does work that way. But my question was if I have to dismiss modules at all when doing unit tests in TypeScript or if there is another way, where I can keep the modules.

Comment: You can keep as many modules as you want. But why would you want to if you are using external modules anyways.

Comment: Can I run my unit tests without treating my app's codebase as external module?

Comment: Not easily. Have external modules all the way. Checkout webpack

Comment: Since I've marked your answer as solution can you please add a note that explicitely states that one should NOT use modules at all?
Will be a direct answer to the original question. Thanks.