# How can I reference normal typescript module(A.ts) from ambient module(B.d.ts)?

Tags: import, enums, reference, typescript, ambient

Initially I declared everything in ambient module. 
Later I had to extract enums to non-ambient module, because I needed enum member lookup, with declare and const its not possible.
Now my sample files look as following

```
//enums.ts
export enum Enum1{
    Value1, Value2
}

//ambient.d.ts
import * as enums from "./enums";
declare interface TypeA
{
  enumField: enums.Enum1;
  strField: string;
}

//consumer.ts
/// <reference path="ambient.d.ts"/>
class Consumer{
 memberField: TypeA; // <= Here compiler cannot find TypeA
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you add line:

```
import * as enums from "./enums";
```

you convert it to external module, and therefore to access its content need to import it, like this:

```
import * as amb from './ambient'
class Consumer
{
    memberField: amb.TypeA; 
}
```

As a side note. Do not use namespaces or try to mix them with modules ([link](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules)).

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but you do not have to add export in the interface ?. I delete this message good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following `import {TypeA} from "./ambient";`

```
import {TypeA} from "./classes/ambient"; //change your path

//consumer.ts
/// <reference path="./classes/ambient.d.ts"/>

class Consumer{
 memberField: TypeA;
}
```

---

```
//ambient.d.ts
import * as enums from "./enums";

export declare interface TypeA
{
  enumField: enums.Enum1;
  strField: string;
}
```