# Namespace is undefined after compile

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify, tsify

I am writing a little game engine in typescript, and when I compile it to javascript, I get an error when running the javascript. It compiles without error too.

My main entry file (**main.ts**) starts with these two lines:

```
require('./core/Obj');
require('./core/Component');
```

It builds out fine but when I run it, the second require has some issues and gives this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a function or null

**core/Obj.ts**

```
namespace GameEngine {
    export class Obj {
        // Some functions/methods
    }
}
```

**core/Component.ts**

```
namespace GameEngine {
    export class Component extends Obj {
    }
}
```

Then once it is compiled, it looks something like this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global) { (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[
    function(require,module,exports){
        var GameEngine;
        (function (GameEngine) {
            class Component extends GameEngine.Obj { // Error is here
            }
            GameEngine.Component = Component;
        })(GameEngine || (GameEngine = {}));
    },{}],
    5:[function(require,module,exports){
        var GameEngine;
        (function (GameEngine) {
            class Obj {
            }
            GameEngine.Obj = Obj;
        })(GameEngine || (GameEngine = {}));
    },{}]
});
```

Here is the gulp task that I am running:

```
gulp.task('compile-engine', function () {
    return browserify()
        .add('./GameEngine/main.ts')
        .plugin(tsify, {})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (error) { throw error; })
        .pipe(source('gameEngine.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Comment: The issue commentary here might be of use to you - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5844 If you're on TS 1.7, try bump up to 1.8?

Answer (score 2):

Each module has its own `GameEngine` namespace - as modules don't pollute the global scope. (In the compiled bundle in your question, you can see that they are separate.) There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357635/6680611) that explains namespaces and modules.

In using `tsify`, you're using (external) modules. Things can be made simpler if you do away with the namespacing. The [TypeScript Handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md#needless-namespacing) has this to say about using namespaces with modules:

> A key feature of modules in TypeScript is that two different modules will never contribute names to the same scope. Because the consumer of a module decides what name to assign it, there's no need to proactively wrap up the exported symbols in a namespace.

You could change the exports and imports to something like this:

### `core/Obj.ts`

```
export class Obj {
    // Some functions/methods
}
```

### `core/Component.ts`

```
import { Obj } from "./Obj";
export class Component extends Obj {
}
```

### `main.ts`

```
import { Component } from "./core/Component";
// Do something with Component
```

Comment: I will give this a try.