# angular 2 namespace model

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I use model-classes in angular 2?

here is an example

Model

```
namespace model.car {
    export class CoolCar {
        Id: string;
        Name: string;

        constructor(){
        }
    }

    export class NiceCar {
        Id: string;
        Name: string;

        constructor(){
        }
    }
}

namespace model.bike {
    export class AwesomeBike {
        Id: string;
        Name: string;

        constructor(){
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use them in my classes like

```
var car=new model.car.CoolCar();
```

but when I run this in my browser I get an error

```
"ReferenceError: 'model' is undefined"
```

I tried to Import the model-classes like

```
import {CoolCar} from '../model/car/CoolCar'
```

but then I get an error in VS2015:

```
File "c:/...../model/car/CoolCar.ts is" no module
```

Could anybody help me here?

Tobias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use keyword `export` if you want to expose namespaces. For example:

```
// MyModels.ts
export namespace car {
    export class NiceCar {
        Id: string;
        constructor(public name: string) {}
    }
}

export namespace bike {
    export class AwesomeBike {
        Id: string;
        constructor(public name: string) { }
    }
}
```

Then use these namespaces with:

```
// main.ts
import * as model from './MyModels';

let car = new model.car.NiceCar('my nice car');
let bike = new model.bike.AwesomeBike('my awesome bike');

console.log(car);
console.log(bike);
```

Note I'm importing these classes under `model` namespace that is specified only when importing and not in `MyModels.ts`.

This when compiled to JS and run will print to console:

```
$ node main.js 
NiceCar { name: 'my nice car' }
AwesomeBike { name: 'my awesome bike' }
```

Note that it's generally discouraged to use namespaces in TypeScript. See [How do I use namespaces with TypeScript external modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you.

**cars.ts**

```
export namespace Cars {
    export class CoolCar { /* ... */ }
    export class NiceCar { /* ... */ }
}
```

**coolcar.ts**

```
import * as car from "./cars";
let c = new cars.Cars.CoolCar();
```

[Typescript Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html)