# Cannot reference declared file in module when class is inside the same module

Tags: typescript, declaration

I have this declaration file: `decl.d.ts`.

```
declare module MyModule {
  export class MyClass {}
}
```

And my source file: `file.ts`.

```
/// <reference path="./decl.d.ts"/>

export module MyModule {
  export class MyOtherClass {
    myFunction(): void {
      var myvar: MyModule.MyClass;
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is that `MyModule.MyClass` is not recognized. But if I remove the module in `file.ts`, I can reference the class.

What is going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules/

Comment: That is, `file.ts` is itself a module, the full name of `MyModule` inside `file.ts` is something like `file.MyModule` and it's different from `MyModule` in `decl.d.ts`