# When to use declare module and declare namespace

Tags: typescript

I was [going through one of the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/reactxp/blob/master/src/typings/react-native-extensions.d.ts) to see how people structure their ts repo.

I went through their typings and saw this

```
/**
 * react-native-extensions.d.ts
 *
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 *
 * Type definition file that extends the public React Native type definition file.
 */

    import * as React from 'react';
    import * as RN from 'react-native';
    import * as RNW from 'react-native-windows';
    
    declare module 'react-native' {
        interface ExtendedViewProps extends RN.ViewProps

 {
```

Now, I am unable to figure out when should we use `declare module` or `declare namespace`? The closest I was able to come across with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932585/what-is-the-difference-between-declare-namespace-and-declare-module) on stackoverflow but I think this shares the difference between the both and not when to use them (and which one to use)

The typescript handbook states this

**This post outlines the various ways to organize your code using modules and namespaces in TypeScrip**

And I wasn't able to comprehend the definition of the above.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `declare module` and `declare namespace` are most useful in the context of [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). Basically, since in Javascript you can monkeypatch the prototypes of classes or add properties to third party classes, declaration merging gives you a way of exposing those dynamic changes to the behaviour of an object in the type system.

For example, consider the [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object from express.js. The API exposed by express does not expose something like a field for a request id. However, it is customary in javascript to simply mutate the request object.

```
middlware(req, res, next) {
  req.id = uuid.v4()
  next()
}
```

Typescript doesn't like this however because with the normal express type definitions, `id` is not a property of request. You can fix by using `declare module` and declaration like this:

```
import { Request } from "express";
import core from "express-serve-static-core";

declare module "express" {
  interface Request<
    P extends core.Params = core.ParamsDictionary,
    ResBody = any,
    ReqBody = any,
    ReqQuery = core.Query
  > {
    /**
     * An optional request id that can be attached to the request. Useful for correlating
     * and searching log messages.
     */
    id?: string;
  }
}
```

If you include this file in your type path, Typescript will be happy to accept the optional `id` property of Request. The use case for `declare namespace` is similar.