# Using Custom Entity inside Express Request Extension

Tags: typescript, express, jwt, typeorm

I am making a basic API with express, typeORM and JWT

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62631740/17537072) to attach my users information to the Request in my middleware and it worked well.

But I decided that keeping only my usersId was not enough so I tried to save the entire User TypeOrm entity, but immediately I got the following error:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
```

So basically I have this extension

```js
import { User } from "../entities/User";

declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user: User;
    }
}
```

when I use it I get the following error
[image]

To me this makes absolutely no sense to me, because when I change it to this:

```js
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        user: string;
    }
}
```

it works perfectly fine

[image]

Could there be a hidden error that I am missing? could this be a bug at the frameworks level?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

class User {
  name: string = '';
}

declare module 'express' {
  export interface Request {
    user: User;
  }
}

function controller(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const newUser = new User();
  req.user = newUser;
}
```

package version:

```json
"express": "^4.17.1",
"@types/express": "^4.17.11"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand your solution, I found this answer that explains the difference. Ill left it here as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932585/what-is-the-difference-between-declare-namespace-and-declare-module