# Constructor error using namespace in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to use constructors inside a class using namespace, but every time I want to push an object into array, i get an typerror, this doesn't happen when I'm not using namespace

why i'm getting this error just for use namespace?

these are my test classes

**1.ts**

```
namespace pruebas {

export class User {

    private _name: string;
    private _ape: string;
    constructor(name,ape){
        this._name = name;
        this._ape = ape;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    get ape(): string {
        return this._ape;
    }

    set ape(value: string) {
        this._ape = value;
    }
}
}
```

**2.ts**

```
///<reference path="1.ts"/>
namespace pruebas {
import pr = pruebas.User;

let us = new User(`saresease`, `ssfse`);
let vw = new User(`ghrebbre`, `bnerev`);
let r =[]
r.push(us,vw);
console.log(r)
}
```

This is the error

```
    var us = new pruebas.User("saresease", "ssfse");
         ^

TypeError: pruebas.User is not a constructor
at pruebas (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\src\testnames\2.js:4:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\src\testnames\2.js:9:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Comment: Don't use namespaces or `outFile` without being mindful of the hazards https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile with `--outFile` for this to work.

More generally, since you're running a node process, you shouldn't be putting things into the global namespace, as this won't really work for long (as soon as you need to `import` some other thing, this all falls apart). Use top-level `export` and `import` declarations to share components between files.

See also [How do I use namespaces with TypeScript external modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules)

Answer (score 0):

### you can use namespace in a module after you export it.

1.export the namespace in **1.ts**.

```
export = pruebas;
```

2.import the namespace using *import=require(..)* in **2.ts**.

```
import pruebas=require("./1.ts");
```

### you can use namespace as global library.

> you must compile **2.ts** & **1.ts** into a single script file.if you define **1.ts** as both global library and a module,you must specify a module loader via option **--module=amd**/**--module=system** when using `tsc` compile .ts into a single .js file.

1. using triple-slash directive to define your dependency in **2.ts**.

   ```
   ///<reference path="./1.ts"/>;
   ```
2. compile the 2.ts with `tsc --outFile 2.js <srcRoot>/2.ts`,then add the js in browser you can see the result.if you want to see details,[let's go!!!](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-acess-files)