# TypeScript: Export React components as part of a namespace

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following files:

AutosuggestComponent.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';

interface AutosuggestProps {
    ...
}    

interface AutosuggestState {
   ...
}

export default class Autosuggest extends React.Component<AutosuggestProps, AutosuggestState> {
    ...
}
```

And I would like to import the Autosuggest component like this in ConsumerComponent.tsx:

```
import Autosuggest = Components.AutoSuggest;
```

How can I export AutosuggestComponent.tsx in order to make this work?

I have tried creating an Autosuggest.ts like this:

```
import AutosuggestComponent from './AutosuggestComponent';

namespace Components {
    export const Autosuggest = AutosuggestComponent;
}
```

which doesn't work. The ConsumerComponent then cannot find the namespace 'Components'. 
However, this works:

```
// import AutosuggestComponent from './AutosuggestComponent';

namespace Components {
    export const Autosuggest = { dummyValue: "test" }
}
```

As soon as I comment out the import, the ConsumerComponent is able to find the namespace. Why?

Is there any way to work this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reach the desired behavior by structuring your code in the following manner:

Add extra ts file named index.ts in the folder where all your components reside:

```
export * from './Autosuggest';
export * from './Combobox';
```

Then consume it from your ConsumerComponent.tsx:

```
import * as Components from './components/index';
import Autosuggest = Components.AutoSuggest;
```

The reason for it not working with `import` is due to the fact that by using import you are turning it into [module](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/modules.html) (even though you are using namespace keyword) where 'Components' are not exported. And I would recommend try not to use namespaces at all, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules), [and here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/namespaces.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't seem to get this to work. When importing Components.AutoSuggest I get this errormessage: Property 'Autosuggest' does not exist on type 'typeof "c:/Projects/portal/Scripts/Shared/Components/index

Comment: Try to remove `default` from Autosuggest class definition, keep it like this: `export class Autosuggest`

Comment: I believe this pattern is called a Barrel

Answer (score 1):

index.ts

```
import { A } from './A.tsx';
import { B } from './B.tsx';

export const C = {
  A,
  B,
}
```

using:

```
import { C } from './index';

<C.A/>
<C.B/>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

Typescript version 3.8.3

Comment: An explanation would be better