# Creating Namespaces in Typescript 2.x

Tags: typescript, namespaces, typescript2.0

I have read (again) the docs of Typescript to clear things out about modules and namespaces but I still have some dark points.

1. `declare namespace Foo{}`
2. `namespace Foo{}`
3. `export namespace Foo{}`

Among those 3 ways to create a namespace, what is the intended use of each one?

Let's say I want to create a **Validation** namespace and I have 3 files that contribute to that namespace. What is the correct way of doing this and how I am going to import(use) the code in Validation namespace from another file/module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct way of doing this and how I am going to
>   import(use) the code in Validation namespace from another file/module?

When you are saying "import(use)" and "file/module" in a single question, you are asking about two very different situations, and the answer is different for each one.

There is no way to do that with `import` and modules. Each module is a distinct, separate scope, and if you define `namespace Validation` in each module you will create 3 different namespaces because declarations from different scopes are not merged. Well, you can break out of module scope by using `declare global`, but it defeats the stated purpose of modules -
 elimination of globals.

You can do that with files which are not modules - that is, files that don't have any toplevel `import` or `export`. But then, you are restricted to non-modular javascript (or typescript). Your `namespace Validation` will be in the global scope, you can't use `import` and modules, and you have to compile and concatenate all files together, producing single script suitable for loading with a `<script>` tag.

See also [How do I use namespaces with TypeScript external modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules)

As for specific syntax variants

```
declare namespace Foo {}
```

This declares that there exists namespace Foo, defined in some external file (not included in the current compilation), allowing to use `Foo` which is assumed to contain things declared within `{}` (and `{}` may contain only declarations, not definitions here)

```
namespace Foo {}
```

This creates namespace `Foo`

```
export namespace Foo {}
```

This also creates namespace Foo, but `export` can have different meaning, depending on where it appears in the source file (it also depends on whether the file is a module or not, but I don't want to go into details of how `export` is useful without modules).

If `export` is at the top level, it turns the file into a module, and makes `Foo` available for importing and using (but not extending) in other modules. If `export` is not at the top level, then again it depends: if it's in some exported namespace, it defines nested namespace, accessible by modules which imported that outer namespace. If it is in non-exported namespace, `export` has no effect I believe.