# How to split namespaced type declarations into multiple files yet be able to import as single namespace in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I'm trying to achieve the following:
(Never mind that the types are structured the same. This is for demo purpose only). The goal is to not have a single large file for the namespace I'd like to export.

```
import Animal from 'types/animal/index.ts'

const dog:Animal.Dog = {
  sound: 'bark',
  legs: 4
}

const cat:Animal.Cat = {
  sound: 'meow',
  legs: 4
}
```

**types/animal/index.ts**

```
// somehow import the animal types from separate files and export in one "Animal" namespace
```

**types/Cat.ts**

```
export namespace Animal {
  export interface Cat {
    sound: string
    legs: number
  }
}
```

**types/Dog.ts**

```
export namespace Animal {
  export interface Dog {
    sound: string
    legs: number
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `Dog.ts` and `Cat.ts` indeed reside in `types`, and not in `types/animal`, something like this in `types/animal/index.ts` should do the job:

```
import * as Animal_Dog from '../Dog';
import * as Animal_Cat from '../Cat';


namespace Animal {
    export type Dog = Animal_Dog.Animal.Dog;
    export type Cat = Animal_Cat.Animal.Cat;
}

export default Animal;
```