# Build for both browser and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser

I am trying to make a library that works both in the browser as well as in node.

I have three json config files where the latter two extend `tsconfig.json`

- tsconfig.json (just contains files for the build)
- tsconfig.browser.json
- tsconfig.node.json

**tsconfig.browser.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "outFile": "../dist/browser/libjs.js",
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.node.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "../dist/node/typings"
  },
  "files": [
    "./index"
  ]
}
```

I have this **index.ts** file (only included on the node build):

```
export { collect } from './components/collections'
export { query } from './components/query'
```

Then I have this in the **collections.ts** file:

```
export namespace libjs {
  export function collect<T>(data: T[]) {
    // Do some stuff
  }
  export class collection(){}
}
```

And this **query.ts** file:

```
export namespace libjs {
  export class query<T> {
    private _results: collection<T>
  }
}
```

The issue I am having, is when I try to build to node, the index file cannot find the `collect` function, and when I build to the browser the `query` class cannot find the `collection` class. What is the best way to code this so I can build to both node and the browser? If I remove the `export` on the `namespace` I can build to the browser fine, but I cannot build to node.

The way I would like to use these are as follows:

**Nodejs**

```
const libjs = require('libjs')
let c = libjs.collect([1, 123, 123, 1231, 32, 4])
```

**Browser**

```
<script src="/js/libjs.js"></script>
<script>
    let c = libjs.collect([1, 123, 123, 1231, 32, 4])
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile files that have `export ...` at the top level, each file is treated as a module with its own scope, and `namespace libjs` in each file is distinct and separate from `libjs` in every other file.

If you want to generate a single script that can be used in a browser without module loader (defining `libjs` as global), you have to remove all toplevel exports, and don't set `module` at all in `tsconfig`:

**components/collections.ts**

```
namespace libjs {
  export function collect<T>(data: T[]) {
    // Do some stuff
  }
  export class collection<T>{}
}
```

**components/query.ts**

```
namespace libjs {
  export class query<T> {
    private _results: collection<T>
  }
}
```

Now, you can use the same generated script in node too, if you add code that detects node environment at runtime and assigns `libjs` to `module.exports`:

**index.ts**

```
namespace libjs {
    declare var module: any;
    if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
        module.exports = libjs;
    }
}
```

single **tsconfig.json** for browser and node (note that I changed output to `dist` from `../dist`)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outFile": "./dist/libjs.js",
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "files": [

    "components/collections.ts",
    "components/query.ts",
    "index.ts"

  ]
}
```

You can use generated script right away in node in javascript:

**test-js.js**

```
const lib = require('./dist/libjs')

console.log(typeof lib.collect);
let c = lib.collect([1, 123, 123, 1231, 32, 4])
```

Unfortunately, you can't use it in node in typescript with generated `libjs.d.ts` because it declares `libjs` as global. For node, you need separate `libjs.d.ts` that contains one additional `export = libjs` statement that you have to add manually or as part of build process:

complete **dist/libjs.d.ts**  for node

```
declare namespace libjs {
    function collect<T>(data: T[]): void;
    class collection<T> {
    }
}
declare namespace libjs {
    class query<T> {
        private _results;
    }
}
declare namespace libjs {
}

// this line needs to be added manually after compilation
export = libjs;
```

**test-ts.ts**

```
import libjs = require('./dist/libjs');
console.log(typeof libjs.collect);
let c = libjs.collect([1, 123, 123, 1231, 32, 4])
```

**tsconfig.test.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./test-ts.ts",
    "./dist/libjs.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

You can choose to go a completely different route and build a library composed of modules, but for that you have to use module loader in the browser (or build with webpack), and you probably need to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules) explaining why `namespace libjs` is totally unnecessary with modules.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, as I get the following error in node: `TypeError: libjs.collect is not a function`

Comment: Okay, I have got this working, however, when I build to the browser, it wraps in in `System.register("libjs", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {` Then when I try to access it in the browser I get an error saying `System` is not defined.

Comment: I now realize this answer is completely off-track. If you need everything in a single script without modules in browser, the only way is to remove all toplevel exports. Then for node, you can use the same compiled script, but for that you need to assign `libjs` to `module.exports` dynamically if the script runs in node. I'm going to test that and rewrite the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to make a change to the index file so it looks like this for it to work the way I want (removed the namespace and added an else): `interface Window {
  libjs: any
}
declare var module: any;
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  module.exports = libjs;
} else {
  window.libjs = libjs;
}`