# Split TypeScript namespaces between files - Intellisense Error

Tags: typescript, namespaces, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I am new to TypeScript and trying to not get off to a bad start.  Using TypeScript 2.5.3 within Visual Studio 2017 I am getting intellsense errors saying "Duplicate Identifier 'MyCo'".  Am I doing something wrong here and if so how should I be doing this?  The code runs as desired but VS intellisense is calling this an error.

MyCo.TestSuite1.ts

```
namespace MyCo {
  export class TestSuite1 {
    run() {
      alert("MyCo.TestSuite1.run");
    }
  } 
}
```

MyCo.TestSuite2.ts

```
namespace MyCo {
  export class TestSuite2 {
    run() {
      alert("MyCo.TestSuite2.run");
    }
  } 
}
```

App.ts

```
/// <reference path="MyCo.TestSuite1.ts" />
/// <reference path="MyCo.TestSuite2.ts" />

namespace MyCo {
  export class Main {
    run() {
      var ts1 = new MyCo.TestSuite1();
      ts1.run();
      var ts2 = new MyCo.TestSuite2();
      ts2.run();
    }
  }
}

(function () {
  var main = new MyCo.Main();
  main.run();
})();
```

Comment: You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules) first and think if you need that namespaces at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a runtime error of "exports undefined" when trying the proposed import.  I can't seem to find an example that actually works :(

Comment: @MikeO,Please try to right click the solution and clean, restart VS , delete .vs folder and bin/obj folders under the solution folder. If you installed the ReSharper, empty the ReSharper cache: ReSharper > Options > Environment > General > Clear Caches and disable and enable ReSharper: Tools > Options > ReSharper > General > Suspend / Restore.

Answer (score 0):

You Main class is :

```
 export class Main {
    run() {
      var ts1 = new MyCo.TestSuite1();
      ts1.run();
      var ts2 = new MyCo.TestSuite2();
      ts2.run();
    }
```

but your `MyCo.TestSuite1.ts`  has `export class TestSuite2` not TestSuite1
Check class names in your .ts file

Comment: Oops copied the wrong code for TestSuite1 example.  Fixed now.  As I said, the code runs as expected, I just get an intellisense error.

Comment: Can you check Typescript version from open Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > IntelliSense
If you need it.Change Use TypeScript version

Comment: There is no version property in any of those tabs, but under project properties TypeScript Build its set to use 2.5.