# Best way to expose types to consumers when using typescript to create libraries/packages?

Tags: typescript, module

I've been searching and reading related information on this for a while, but still cannot get my head around this.

When I create a library or package using typescript, I like to set `declaration` to true so that when ts compiler compiles the source code, it will automatically generate declaration files for me. A typical library or package usually has an entry file and a bunch of files dependent with each other. So the outputs for the build result would look like this:

```
.
├── build
|   ├── entry.js (or entry.min.js in production)
|   ├── entry.d.ts (it depends on moduleA)
|   ├── moduleA.d.ts (it depends on moduleB)
|   ├── moduleB.d.ts
|   ├── types.d.ts (contains shared types for every body)
|   └── util.d.ts (declarations for some random util functions)
```

In `package.json`, I would just set this:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./build/entry.js",
  "types": "./build/entry.d.ts",
  ...
}
```

The problem is even though `entry.js` has all the APIs I would like to expose to consumers, `entry.d.ts` doesn't have all the types I would like to also expose. That's because even though `entry.ts` has `import`s from `types.ts`, the type declarations will not be automatically imported from it. The consumer may want to use some enums I kept in `types.ts` (thus `types.d.ts`), which is not in `entry.ts` (thus `entry.d.ts`).

One way to use the types is to re-export it in the entry file, something like:

```
export * from './types';
// or
export { EnumA } from './types';
```

Which will allow consumer to do this:

```
import * as types from 'mylib';
// or 
import { EnumA } from 'mylib';
```

This is what I am doing right now, which is more of a manual workflow and there is a good chance that I forget to export some types that a consumer actually needs to use my library. I could just put all of my types/interfaces/enums in one single `types.ts` file and export everything, but I am not sure if that's the right thing to do.

typescript team is using namespaces to handle this (for example, [server types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/server/types.ts) and [service types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/services/types.ts)), but IMO that is redundant as we are already using ES6 modules. More on that in this post [great cup example for explaining namespaces with modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules).

Another workaround of this is to let consumer do

```
import * as types from 'mylib/build/types'
```

But IMO this is also a bad practise since we are essentially exposed implementation details to consumers, which we may change in the future.

I also want to add to above that if I want to generate library for ES5 codes with commonjs or AMD structure, the [typescript offical document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) says to use `export =`. Apparently, this will prevent you from using `export * from './types'` anymore so the above workarounds will not working anymore.

That's where I am right now. Any suggestions? Right now I am leaning towards to use namespace like what typescript teams does, but I would like to hear more thoughts.

Comment: I also want to add on top of this question, that this type-finding thing could get really bad if you need to access a type that lives deep in the dependency chain. You would essentially need to import a type from a long path