# How to write type-declarations for namespace-structured modules

Tags: typescript, namespaces, declaration, typescript-declarations

So I'm trying to refactor the type-declaration of a module called `inquirer` which is strictly namespace-structured.

I really don't like having one single file with 1k lines of code inside of it, so I tried to split the whole type-declaration up into multiple files and got lots of trouble doing so.

## General

As I mentioned I'm writing type-declarations for a module called `inquirer` which is not working with es6-modules.

For example the exported member itself is an object of type `PromptModule` and a namespace with some classes and interfaces at the same time:

```
import inquirer = require("inquirer");
let question: inquirer.Question = { /* This is a question */ };
inquirer.prompt(question);
inquirer.restoreDefaultPrompts();
inquirer.registerPrompt({ /* this is a prompt */ });
let x = new inquirer.ui.Prompt();
```

Sadly I really couldn't find a way to split the inquirer-module up into separate files for each interface and/or class.

The only way I found was to perform a namespace-merge which is nicely described in a comment of @Ryan Cavanaugh [right below the "Version 2"-heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules).

Sadly I could not export the merged namespace in my `index.d.ts`-file.

This leads me to my question:

- Is there even a way to reach this goal?
- How can I wrap up the inquirer-module into a nice-to-maintain type-declaration?