# namespacing in typescript from PHP coder's classmap and PSR-4

Tags: typescript

I come from PHP background and now I'm diving into typescript code.

In PHP with composer's classmap and the composer.json I can declare namespaces PSR-4 style and as long as I import them properly with the `USE`, it will resolve.

Reading the following:
[How do I use namespaces with TypeScript external modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules)

didn't help me resolve the question:
 - is there something in Typescript that will help resolve paths of classes instead of dealing with relative path" as currently I have to `../..` all the way to root and then go fetch the classes I created within the app directory.

node_modules does not suffer from this path problem (i.e: I can be in the test folder and call `import * as 'restify';` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up path aliases in your tsconfig.json. For example, if tsconfig.json had the following:

```
// ... other config omitted
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
    "components/*": ["components/*"]
  }
```

Then you could import stuff from src/components like this:

```
import Whatever from 'components/Whatever';
```

See documentation on module resolution here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping