# how to use typescript namespace in two separate files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, namespaces

this is my project structure:

```
app ->
    Core ->
        Client.ts
        ClientCollection.ts
```

Client.ts:

```js
namespace Core {
    export class Client { }
}
```

ClientCollection.ts:

```js
namespace Core {
    export class ClientCollection {

        public client: Client; 
    }
}
```

I want to define a variable in `ClientCollection` from the kind of Client.

I use the `/// <reference path = "Client.ts" />` but get me this error: `Cannot find name 'Client'`

How can I do it?

Comment: Read this before using namespaces https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules/30357635#30357635

Comment: Are these supposed to be global scripts? Why not use modules?

Comment: You are defining global namespaces. Ideally you should not receive that error!

Comment: Side topic - the statement "public client: Client;" will give error -Property 'client' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)