# export namespace in namespace

Tags: typescript, javascript-namespaces

Can I export a namespace A with another namespace B in it? Something like:

```
// b.ts
export namespace B {
  export const val = 'val';
}
```

```
// a.ts
export namespace A {
  //... some thing import b as namespace 
}
```

--- above will be export as a module and depended by another project C;

```
// c.ts
import { B } from 'A';

const a = B.val;
```

And I hope ts show me 'namespace B' in C instead of 'import B', which seems to be impossible ;

another question is: if I can split namespace B into multi files when I export, like:

```
// b2.ts
export namespace B {
  export const val2 = 'val2';
}
```

and it can be imported in C

```
// c.ts
import { B } from 'A';

const b2 = B.val2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and finally came across [this answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20990) on the Typescript Github repo.

The work around is as follows:

```
// b.ts (no change here)
export namespace B {
  export const val = 'val';
}
```

in a.ts

```
// a.ts
import {B as _b} from './b.ts'
export namespace A {
  export import B = _b
}
```

And finally in C.ts

```
import { A } from './a.ts'
const b2 = A.B.val;
```

As for the second part of your question, i think [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5395) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules) may help you out.