# Merge namespaces inside `declare global` and `declare module`

Tags: typescript

I'm using Cypress for testing. In its `support/commands.ts` file I see the following:

```
declare module Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    login(email?: string, password?: string);
  }
}
```

This is the place where I add custom commands used on `cy` object `Cypress.Commands.add('login',...)` used like this `cy.login()`.

Now I want to add 3rd party library that extends `Cypress.Commands` with the command `matchImageSnapshot` and defines types like this in `@types/cypress-image-snapshot`:

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            matchImageSnapshot(nameOrOptions?: string | Options): void;
          }
    }
}
```

Once I import the command to `support/commands.ts` like this:

```
import { addMatchImageSnapshotCommand } from 'cypress-image-snapshot/command';
```

I get the error that commands defined in `support/commands.ts` are not valid:

> TS2345: Argument of type '"logout"' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'keyof Chainable '.

Based on some reading, I understand that using `import` in `support/commands.ts` turns this file into ES module (TS external module), right? And namespaces can't be merged between modules as I understand.

It also seems like the definition from `@types/cypress-image-snapshot` takes over the namespace declaration in `support/commands.ts` since if I add `login` command to the declaration in `@types/cypress-image-snapshot` the error is gone:

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            matchImageSnapshot(nameOrOptions?: string | Options): void;

            login():void;  <----- my command from `support/commands.ts`
                                  ¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
        }
    }
}
```

How do I solve this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules), that suggests that you can't merge namespaces between ES modules (external modules), it follows that you can't merge namespaces between `global` scope and a module.

It means that to fix the problem, declaration of both namespaces have to be in the global scope. So I had to wrap `declare namespace Cypress {}` in `support/commands.ts` into global scope like this:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
      login(email?: string, password?: string);
    }
  }
}
```

which solved the problem for me.