# Can't export nested namespaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make the code cleaner by creating namespaces in different directories and then exporting them all through one namespace.

Here's what I'm doing that works:

```js
export namespace Main {
    export namespace Foo { // <-- this works
        
    }
}
```

But importing Foo from another file and exporting it to Main does not work: ie

```js
// foo.ts
export namespace Foo {
}

// main.ts
import { Foo } from './foo.ts'
export namespace Main {
    export namespace Foo = Foo; // <- invalid syntax
}
```

I've googled so much and I just can't find the syntax how do I export Foo if it exists in another file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/how-do-i-use-namespaces-with-typescript-external-modules but that doesn't answer the question on how to assing namespace

Comment: I don't see anything inside that question that solves my problem

Comment: @TanekLoc Yes it does