# Import symbols from one file/namespace into another file with the same namespace

Tags: typescript, import, module, namespaces

I've got a Typescript module with multiple source files, each defining symbols in the same namespace 'aaa'. I need to import a symbol from one file into another:

a.ts:

```
export namespace aaa {
  export const A = 1;
}
```

b.ts:  ***Does not work***

```
export namespace aaa {
  export const B = A + 1;
}
```

I can't import `aaa.A` into `b.ts`. At best I can do:

b.ts:  ***Works***

```
import { aaa as bbb } from "./a";

export namespace aaa {
  export const B = bbb.A + 1;
}
```

I feel like there is a better way to do this. What I would really like to do is have the compiler understand that aaa namespace in a.ts is the same namespace as in b.ts. I should be able to address `A` from inside `b.ts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Following from the docs on [Multi-file namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#multi-file-namespaces).

> ...Even though the files are separate, they can each contribute to the same namespace and can be consumed as if they were all defined in one place. Because there are dependencies between files, we’ll add **reference tags** to tell the compiler about the relationships between the files. Our test code is otherwise unchanged.

So we need to apply a reference tag in order to let the compiler know that `b.ts` is dependent on knowing the contents of `a.ts` first.

`b.ts`:

```js
/// <reference path="a.ts" />
namespace aaa {
  export const B = A + 1;
}
```

Notice how there is no `export`! This is on purpose, this is because this will pollute the global scope with `aaa`.

**You cannot use a reference tag with an exported namespace**, because by the very existence of the `export` keyword it becomes a module, and a module will add create it's own scope, so if it is present the two `aaa`'s are now distinctly scoped.

There are ways to go about it without polluting your global scope, (and you've already discovered that way).

### Don't use Namespaces and Modules

The [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) doesn't recommend using both modules and namespaces. Namespaces has been the old way to do logical naming to prevent name collisions before modern JS/TS. Modules have since taken over that role, and to use both in one file... a headache.

> It is also worth noting that, for Node.js applications, modules are the default and **we recommended modules over namespaces in modern code.**

If it is for the sake of simply organizing code there is a topic on it: [Needless Namespacing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#needless-namespacing)

> A key feature of modules in TypeScript is that two different modules will never contribute names to the same scope. Because the consumer of a module decides what name to assign it, there’s no need to proactively wrap up the exported symbols in a namespace.

There is also an excellent description of it all in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357635/17954209) to the question: [*How do I use namespaces with TypeScript external modules?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357634/) Which will do a much better job explaining it all and is a highly recommended read.

Comment: Much thanks. If you couldn't tell, I came from a c++ background, so my first impulse was to encapsulate everything with namespaces. But that ethos doesn't really work with Typescript modules. The modules ARE the namespace. You resolve namespace collisions on import.